# From Suspend directly to desktop?

Tags: 18.04, suspend, login-screen

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I have disabled the lock screen but enabled suspend mode after 10 minutes.

Each time my PC goes into suspend mode, the first thing that I see when I move the mouse is a protection screen:

[image]

Then I have to click the bottom arrow and move it to the top.

Is it possible to disable the protection screen? So that I am directly on my desktop after moving the mouse?

Comment: Don't have an 18.04 using gnome-shell but you could try this. First check that this key exists, `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend`  If it returns `true` then go ahead and switch, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend false`  Then  ck., a log out/in may or may not be required. An icon may show up for a moment over desktop screen, can ignore.., not sure how to get rid of